# Preventing QGIS to Add XYZ Tiled Layer

Tags: qgis, tiles, tilestache, tile-layer

I have created tiles of raster datasets using TileStache. After creating those tiles i have uploaded them in **S3 Bucket**, and now serving them in my web application as TiledLayer ({z}/{x}/{y}.png)

I have built CORS on the S3 Bucket as well. But the problem is QGIS does not take CORS headers into account, and i can simply create XYZ Tiled Layer with the bucket URL  of the Network from application.

How can i prevent QGIS to add my TiledLayer service. We can build the username and password on it, but that will be exposed in the network as well.